# Flume agent appending extra '\n' after every line write

Tags: java, hadoop, flume-ng

I am using my custom configuration as below for flume agent

```
# Name the components on this agent
agent.sources = r1
agent.sinks = k1
agent.channels = c1

# Describe the source
agent.sources.r1.type = org.apache.flume.source.AvroSource
agent.sources.r1.bind = 192.168.1.31
agent.sources.r1.port = 43999

# Describe the sink
agent.sinks.k1.type = com.zaloni.bedrock.collection.flume.sink.BedrockAvroHDFSEventSink
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = /user/bedrock/sentimentAnalysis/TweetData
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollInterval = 300
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollSize = 1000
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollCount = 100
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text

# Describe the channel
agent.channels.c1.type = org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel

# bind the source and sink to the channel
agent.sources.r1.channels = c1
agent.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

Using the above configurations, I am sending my Stream Data from Java Program to AVRO source. When Flume agent writes the output to HDFS then it appends one extra '\n' character at the end of each line.

Below is the output sample

```
@VermaAmrutaRT @AnjneyaParashar: IBM Watson can now transcribe speech perfectly #ibm #watson #transcription http://t.co/pm5iyLXOOe06-17-2015 13:35:00 +0530 #IBM1

@ThomasLaceyEire#IBM @IBM_DS_Europe  https://t.co/c3ybimNkc606-17-2015 13:35:00 +0530#CSCO1

@INQRT @IBMPowerSystems: #IBM and @OpenPOWERorg encouraging #OpenSource all around the world: http://t.co/duyPrzaZL6 via @ChrisTheDJ @INQ06-17-2015 13:35:00 +0530 #IBM1
```

In the above output each extra line with blank-space is having '\n' character.

Conclusion: Why am I getting extra '\n' character? what might be possible solutions for it?

Comment: Since this is not the expected behaviour from Avro sink, the only possibility is your Java program is sending empty events, one after each real event. Can you paste your data sending code?

Comment: LOG.info("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + ctrlA + status.getText().replaceAll(lineDelim, " ")
      + ctrlA + formatDate(status.getCreatedAt()) + ctrlA + findKeyword(status.getText(), keywords)
      + ctrlA + twitterCategorizer.classifyNewTweet(status.getText()));